# Show that each subset $A \subsetneq \Bbb R$ has atleast one point that's a limit point, but not an internal point.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that each subset $A \subsetneq \Bbb R$ has atleast one edgepoint. That means a point that's a limit point but not an internal point.

So we know that $\Bbb R$\ $A \neq \emptyset$, and we want to show that there exists a point $x$, with $B(x, \delta) \cap A \neq \emptyset$, but also $B(x, \delta) \nsubseteq A$.

I can see why this is true, but I can't prove it.

Tips and hints are appreciated

Comment: What if $A$ is open? Then $\operatorname{int}(A)=A$, i.e. every point of $A$ is an interior point.

Comment: @Dave A limit point of $A$ doesn't have to be part of $A$.

Comment: @Aaron Ah yes of course. My mistake.

Comment: I think your definition of edgepoint is a bit off. For example, under your definition, $\{0\}$ would have no edgepoints, since it has no limit points. Rather, an edgepoint should be an element of the *closure*, but not the interior. One other key change is that $A$ must be *non-empty*. Do you see why?

Answer (score 2):

You want to find a point in the frontier of $A$, i.e. $\partial A = \bar{A} \setminus \mathring{A}$. If the frontier is empty, we have $\mathring{A}=A=\bar{A}$, so $A$ is both open and closed. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, that implies that $A$ is either empty or equal to $\mathbb{R}$, which is not the case.

Remark : if $A$ is open, the point you've found is not in $A$.

Comment: By convex, do you mean connected?

Comment: I had written connex because "connexe" is the translation of connected in French (my mother tongue). It is now fixed.

Comment: Understandable.  I imagine that there are lots of little difficulties participating in an English-language discussion site for someone whose first language isn't English (although plenty of native speakers have troubles too).  Your contribution, especially in light of language differences, is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be a nonempty and proper subset of $\Bbb R$.

Let $x \in \Bbb R - A$. Either $\ (-\infty , x) \cap A \ \ $ or $\ \ (x,\infty) \cap A \ $ is nonempty (or both).

WLOG assume $(-\infty , x) \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

Then what can you say about 
$$\sup \ (-\infty , x) \cap A$$